# Ruby converting UTC to user's time zone

Tags: ruby

I have `dstring` as saved in UTC. While I have user's timezone's offset `standard_offset`
What I want to show that date in user's timezone after conversion. So this is what I do, but at the end you can see it shows `UTC` not `PST` or `PDT`

```
  [64] pry> dstring
  => "2013-10-31T23:10:50Z"
  [65] pry> standard_offset = -8
  => -8
  [66] pry> e = Time.parse(dstring) + (standard_offset * 3600)
  => 2013-10-31 15:10:50 UTC
  [67] pry> e.strftime("%m/%m/%Y %I:%M %p %Z")
  => "10/10/2013 03:10 PM UTC"
```

I expect finally to get `10/10/2013 03:10 PM PST` How to get that? Note: This is not a rails app.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't use the TZInfo gem? http://rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/file/README.md

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added a method `in_timezone` method in `Time` class as follows:

```
class Time
   require 'tzinfo'
   # tzstring e.g. 'America/Los_Angeles'
   def in_timezone tzstring
     tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get tzstring
     p = tz.period_for_utc self
     e = self + p.utc_offset
     "#{e.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")} #{p.zone_identifier}"
   end
 end
```

How to use it:

```
t = Time.parse("2013-11-01T21:19:00Z")  
t.in_timezone 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Comment: you americans and your inverted month/day dates! ^^
Isn't there a way to get time format from time zone?

Comment: There's actually an ActiveSupport builtin method for this since Rails 3: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/DateTime/in_time_zone

Comment: This almost worked for me. I had to use `p.utc_total_offset` to account for DST. `utc_offset` returned the offset for non-DST.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an issue with the Ruby standard library.

Sources:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/file/README.md

> Note that the local Time returned will have a UTC timezone (local.zone will return "UTC"). This is because the Ruby Time class only supports two timezones: UTC and the current system local timezone.

http://librelist.com/browser//usp.ruby/2011/9/24/unix-time-and-the-ruby-time-class/

> Modern kernels do not know nor care about timezones.  Conversions from
>   UTC to the local timezone (and vice versa) are done in user space[2].
>   Different processes running concurrently on the same machine do not
>   necessarily share the same local timezone.
>
> ### Process timezone
>
> The "TZ" environment variable controls the timezone for a given
>   process, and thus the timezone attached to a Ruby Time object.  If
>   "TZ" is unset, the timezone of the process is implementation-defined.

As far as I can tell, everything related to time zones that is in Rails was built by the Rails core team. Ruby only handles as much time-related functionality as Unix provides and probably expects the user to handle the reset.

Answer (score -2):

```
require 'tzinfo'
class Time
   def in_timezone(tzstring)
     tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get(tzstring)
     p = tz.period_for_utc(self.utc)
     # puts "#{tzstring} -> utc_offset=#{p.utc_offset},utc_total_offset=#{p.utc_total_offset},p.offset=#{p.offset}"
     e = self.utc + p.utc_total_offset
     "#{e.strftime('%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')} #{p.zone_identifier}"
   end
end

[Time.parse("2013-10-20T21:19:00Z"), Time.parse("2013-11-20T21:19:00Z")].each do |t|
    puts '=======================================================> ' + t.to_s
    puts "\t" + t.in_timezone('GMT')
    puts "\t" + "------------------"
    puts "\t" + t.in_timezone('Europe/London')
    puts "\t" + t.in_timezone('Europe/Prague')
    puts "\t" + t.in_timezone('Asia/Jerusalem')
end
```