# How do you convert the following time from UTC to EST in Ruby (without Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I am trying to covert the UTC time "2018-04-02T14:30:00Z" to EST in pure Ruby. I noticed the following discrepancy. If I parse the time in UTC using Rails and then add the EST zone_offset I get a different time than using the "in_time_zone" helper. 9:30 versus 10:30.

```
2.2.4 :001 > t = Time.parse "2018-04-02T14:30:00Z"
 => 2018-04-02 14:30:00 UTC 
2.2.4 :002 > t + Time.zone_offset("EST")
 => 2018-04-02 09:30:00 UTC 
2.2.4 :003 > t.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
 => Mon, 02 Apr 2018 10:30:00 EDT -04:00
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128436/ruby-converting-utc-to-users-time-zone

Answer (score 3):

you can try the `localtime` method, something like `Time.parse("2018-04-02T14:30:00Z").localtime("-05:00").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")` to pretty print to get the time object remove the `strftime`

Answer (score 3):

Rails does time zones really well, and you're going to have a difficult time replicating the results of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#in_time_zone` without just using it.

For example, as you've pointed out:

```
>> t = Time.parse "2018-04-02T14:30:00Z"
>> t.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
Mon, 02 Apr 2018 10:30:00 EDT -04:00
```

But consider that you can likewise do:

```
>> t = Time.parse "2018-01-02T14:30:00Z"
>> t.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
Tue, 02 Jan 2018 09:30:00 EST -05:00
```

In other words, ActiveSupport is handling not only your time zones, but also your Standard/Daylight Savings challenges, all for free. Not even moment.js will do that (or if it will, I haven't figured out how).

Have you considered using `require 'active_support'`, which would give you this functionality without using all of Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" is actually EDT and not EST. That would explain your hour difference.

```
irb(main):014:0> t = Time.parse "2018-04-02T14:30:00Z"
=> 2018-04-02 14:30:00 UTC
irb(main):015:0> t.in_time_zone('EST')
=> Mon, 02 Apr 2018 09:30:00 EST -05:00
irb(main):016:0> t.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Mon, 02 Apr 2018 10:30:00 EDT -04:00
irb(main):017:0>
```

See also: https://time.is/EST
and https://time.is/EDT

Also, timezones are a huge pain and routinely break my brain.